How to run a foreground service with a permission which is defined in the manifest but declined by the user on Android 14
Currently it throws an exception, because the permission is defined in the manifest xml but not granted in runtime by the user. This is a new requirement to define service permission in manifest on Android 14.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required
I need to run the service without using the function that requires the permission. I don't think it's possible.
